# CSP issues with checksession using oidc-client.js

Tags: javascript, identityserver4, content-security-policy, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I'm building a SPA using oidc-client to sign in to an IDP built using Identity Server 4.

The login redirections seems to work fine but on Firefox I'm getting the following CSP issues

[image]

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring "'unsafe-inline'" within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'sha256-VDXN0nOpFPQ102CIVz+eimHA5e+wTeoUUQj5ZYbtn8w='"). Source: !function(t){function __webpack_require_....  checksession:1
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'sha256-VDXN0nOpFPQ102CIVz+eimHA5e+wTeoUUQj5ZYbtn8w='"). Source: window.devToolsOptions = Object.assign(w....  checksession:1
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://localhost:5007/home/error?errorId=a74accc61bb821ee1f42f7013a306e90 does not permit cross-origin framing.  (unknown)
```

I'm not setting any CSP meta tags on my SPA and I'm wondering if I have to.
Digging a little bit it seems that oidc-client is adding an iframe into my application which points to the checksession page in Identity Server (which does include the CSP header "default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'sha256-VDXN0nOpFPQ102CIVz+eimHA5e+wTeoUUQj5ZYbtn8w='")

Can someone help me solving this or lead me into the right direction? My knowledge about CSP is very basic.

Comment: I happen to be diagnosing the exact same issue at the moment.  We are experiencing the behavior in chrome.  I just updated IDSrvr4.  Could be related to https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/659. And or this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854600/identityserver-used-as-external-identity-provider-for-another-identityserver-fai/41862927#answer-41862927

Comment: Are you also experiencing "Frame window timed out" in signinSilent when app is closed while toke expires?  https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/311

Comment: Opended this here.. https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Redux devtools addon trying to inject their code on the page.